# WriteConsoleOutputCharacter crashing the Console Application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, output, console-application

When trying to use the [WriteConsoleOutputCharacter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputcharacter) function, the application crashes.

```
COORD pos;
pos.X = 0;
pos.Y = 0;

HANDLE buffer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
LPDWORD written;

char* str = "s";
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(buffer, str, strlen(str), pos, written);
```

but the WriteConsole function works correctly:

```
WriteConsole(buffer1,str,strlen(str),written,NULL);
```

I'm not getting any error but the Windows "application stopped responding" notification, and i can't use a debugger since the IDE I'm using (Dev C++ 5.11) has a broken one.

Comment: `LPDWORD written` - of course crash. you need use `DWORD written` and `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(buffer, str, strlen(str), pos, &written);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the variable `written` *pointing*? The function will dereference that argument to set the number of characters written. If the variable is not initialized it will have an *indeterminate* value, and be seemingly pointing at a random location, leading to *undefined behavior* when being dereferenced.

Instead use a plain `DWORD` and use the address-of operator `&`:

```
DWORD written;

WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(buffer, str, strlen(str), pos, &written);
//                                                         ^
//                         Note the address-of operator here
```

Or if you're not interested in how many characters were written, pass `nullptr` instead.

Comment: Hm, what's the difference between DWORD and LPDWORD? Pointing to the LPDWORD variable was causing  this error -- cannot convert 'DWORD** {aka long unsigned int**}' to 'LPDWORD {aka long unsigned int*}' --. Instead, pointing to the DWORD variable worked correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @SimoneBondi `LPDWORD` is a macro for `long *`. So if you do `LPDWORD written;` you are basically doing `long *written;`. The `P` stands for *pointer*.